# How to insert an SVG document text manually into a TWebBrowser at run-time?

Tags: delphi, svg, twebbrowser, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 Win32 VCL Application, I need to insert an SVG document manually into a `TWebBrowser` (`wb1.SelectedEngine := IEOnly;`) at run-time:

```
procedure TForm1.btnLoadSVGDocClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: Variant;
  slSVG: TStringList;
begin
  slSVG := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slSVG.LoadFromFile('C:\DELPHI\_test\BrowserSVGViewer\steamreactor.svg');
    // Todo: Make corrections to the SVG document text
    if NOT Assigned(wb1.Document) then
      wb1.Navigate('about:blank');
    Doc := wb1.Document;
    Doc.Clear;
    Doc.Write(slSVG.Text);
    Doc.Close;
    //wb1.Refresh;
  finally
    slSVG.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately, the SVG is not shown in the `TWebBrowser`! What am I doing wrong? I even tried `wb1.Refresh;`, but it does not help.

Comment: Do you really need a TWebBrowser just for showing a SVG image? Maybe you can use this: https://github.com/EtheaDev/SVGIconImageList

Comment: @DelphiCoder compare the rendering of this SVG file: https://svgshare.com/s/Uzf in SVGIconImageList and in a web browser. I have made the comparison :-{=

Comment: @user1580348 is right. Very few libraries can compete with modern web browsers when it comes to SVG rendering. Maybe none.

Comment: *"the SVG is not shown"* Is anything shown?

Comment: @Olivier: No, but if you view the source, you can see the SVG file. I think the IE control expects pure HTML to be written. It doesn't allow you to insert an XML SVG document this way.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Indeed, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752639(v=vs.85)) says *"Writes one or more HTML expressions to a document"*, so it's not really surprising if it fails with SVG content.

Comment: Isn't there any stand-alone SVG-renderer that uses the same SVG rendering engine as a modern browser?

Comment: @user1580348: There are Delphi packages that wraps a Chromium browser.

Comment: Even Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/what-s-new-in-direct2d-for-windows-8-consumer-preview) that you use a web browser if you need full SVG support: "Note that Direct2D only supports a limited subset of SVG suitable for images and does not support all SVG drawing features. If you need browser-grade SVG compatibility or SVG’s web-oriented features, consider using the XAML WebView control instead."

Comment: @user1580348: You can try cairo + librsvg. It gives pretty good results. There are Delphi headers around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Explorer control is not quite designed to be given content on the fly. Therefore, my standard approach is to save my content to a temporary file:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    btnLoadSvg: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoadSvgClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTempFiles: TList<TFileName>;
  public
  end;

implementation

uses
  IOUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTempFiles := TList<TFileName>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FTempFiles) then
    for var TempFile in FTempFiles do
      Winapi.Windows.DeleteFile(PChar(TempFile));
end;

procedure TForm1.btnLoadSvgClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var SvgText := TFile.ReadAllText('K:\flower.svg', TEncoding.UTF8);

  var TempFileName := ChangeFileExt(TPath.GetTempFileName, '.svg');
  FTempFiles.Add(TempFileName);
  TFile.WriteAllText(TempFileName, SvgText, TEncoding.UTF8);
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(TempFileName);

end;
```

This is robust. For instance, even if the user presses F5 while the control has focus, the document will still be there.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice and robust example about using temporary files! BTW, is there no way to insert an SVG document manually into a TWebBrowser as a HTML text at run-time without using the file approach?

Comment: @user1580348: I tried to load an HTML doc with an IMG tag with a base-64-encoded SVG data URI, but that didn't work. We have to remember that the IE control is ten years old and was designed twenty years ago. It's rather legacy. And even if it did work, if the user's cat accidentally hits F5 on a dynamically loaded page, it would simply disappear.

Comment: I don't know whether the other Delphi browser control that uses EDGE is more robust in the long-term?

Comment: @user1580348: I have never got it to work properly.

Comment: @ Are there any cats using Delphi?

Comment: @user1580348: Most cats prefer C# these days. Joking aside, I'd like to add a comment about IE being old. Yes, the 10-year-old IE control doesn't have quite as good SVG support as more recent browsers like Firefox or Chrome (or Edge being based on Chrome), even though of course it outperforms most non-browser renderers. However, it excels when it comes to drawing smooth paths. Microsoft did a really good job there.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an empty frame into WebBrowser1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>SVG Frame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

and add the SVG code by setting outerHTML of the svg tag as follows:

```
var
  Elem: IHTMLElement;
..
Elem := GetElementByTag(WebBrowser1.Document, 'svg');
Elem.outerHTML := slSVG.Text;
```

function GetElementByTag should be defined as follows:

```
function GetElementByTag(const Doc: IDispatch; const TagName: string): IHTMLElement;
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
  I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
begin
  Result := nil;
  // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
  if Tags.length > 0 then
    Result := Tags.item(0, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement
  else
    raise Exception.Create('no <svg> element found!');
end;
```

You need to add unit **mshtml** to **uses** statement.

An example project (Delphi 10.3.3) can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/70jrsbgcs3903eq/SVGinWebbrowser.zip?dl=0)